# How to do dynamic table joins using ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am trying to compose a dynamic query involving a dynamic table join (photos to albums). My first attempt works only on one to many (photos to place):

```
defmodule Test1 do
  def filter_by_place_id(dynamic, id) do
    dynamic([p], ^dynamic and p.place_id == ^id)
  end
end
dynamic =
  true
  |> Test1.filter_by_place_id(248)
```

But this will not work for many to many fields. Which I believe require a table join. So my next attempt:

```
defmodule Test2 do
  def filter_by_place_id({query, dynamic}, id) do
    dynamic = dynamic([p], ^dynamic and p.place_id == ^id)
    {query, dynamic}
  end
  def filter_by_album_id({query, dynamic}, id) do
    query = join(query, :inner, [p], album in assoc(p, :albums), as: :x)
    dynamic = dynamic([{:x, x}], ^dynamic and x.id == ^id)
    {query, dynamic}
  end
end
query = from(p in Photo)
{query, dynamic} =
  {query, true}
  |> Test2.filter_by_place_id(248)
  |> Test2.filter_by_album_id(10)
  |> Test2.filter_by_album_id(11)
```

But this fails because the binding `:x` is hard coded, and obviously I can't reuse it. But I need a binding to ensure that the where clause refers to the correct join.

But if I try to use `as: ^binding` instead of `as :x`, I get the error:

```
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) `as` must be a compile time atom, got: `^binding`
    (ecto 3.6.2) expanding macro: Ecto.Query.join/5
    meow.exs:30: Test2.filter_by_album_id/2
```

So I am not sure where to go from here. Is it possibly to dynamically allocate the binding for a join?

Comment: `dynamic` expressions are allowed for the `join`'s `:on` option -- that might be worth trying because as you've noticed, `:as` expects a hard-coded named binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer gave me an idea, drop the dynamic and just use multiple where clauses. I wasn't sure this would be supported. It looks like multiple where clauses get anded together.

```
def filter_by_value({query, dynamic}, field, id) do                            
  query = join(query, :inner, [p], album in assoc(p, ^field.id))               
  |> where([p, ..., x], x.id == ^id)                                           
  {query, dynamic}                                                             
end
```

Unfortunately this removes the flexibility you get with dynamic, which I would really like, but for now this is an adequate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Bindings can be written in a way: `first, ..., last`

https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html:

> Similarly, if you are interested only in the last binding (or the last bindings) in a query, you can use ... to specify "all bindings before" and match on the last one.

> from [p, ..., c] in posts_with_comments, select: {p.title, c.body}

So try to rewrite `filter_by_album_id`:

```
def filter_by_album_id({query, dynamic}, id) do
    query = join(query, :inner, [p], album in assoc(p, :albums))
    dynamic = dynamic([p, ..., x], ^dynamic and x.id == ^id)
    {query, dynamic}
  end
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work, because we are always using the last binding at the point of the select statement. Which won't be the the correct one if called this function multiple times.

Comment: Did you try it? Last binding is `last` for the moment when the command is applied. So if you use last binding right after join, like I did it in the example, it will work

Comment: Confirmed, doesn't work. The problem being there is nothing linking `dynamic` to the `query` until the `from` statement. So calling `dynamic` from in the function, it has no idea what the bindings are. When it calls the from statement, the last binding gets used.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is hack you can do to binding alias dynamically.
Ecto query is a struct and it has a property `aliases` to store name binding map.

For example you have a query:

```
from(p in Post, join: c in assoc(p, :comments), as: :comments)
```

Then the alias will look like this:

```
%Ecto.Query{
   aliases: %{
     comments: 1
   }
}
```

`comments` is the alias name, and `1` is the position. So you can manually update the alias map.

```
query = from(p in Post, join: c in assoc(p, :comments))
column = :comments

aliases = query.aliases

if Map.has_key?(aliases, column) do
  raise ArgumentError, "Do not allow 2 ref binding with the same name"
end

aliases =
  case Enum.map(aliases, &elem(&1, 1)) do
    [] ->
      %{column => 1}

    positions ->
      max = Enum.max(positions)
      Map.put(aliases, column, max + 1)
  end

# Update the alias map
query = struct(query, aliases: aliases)
```

But this is just a HACK, be aware of that.

I found this when I build my dynamic join query, you can found the source here
https://github.com/bluzky/filtery/blob/6338f53c81608fd44f1eeac0a2ceb108043e56c9/lib/base.ex#L285